# Faster Way to Generate Rolling Calculations on a list of columns within a groupby object

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pandas, cython

I created this function to calculate the rolling stats for a list of feats in my df. This function works as intended but takes roughly 30 min to run on my df which has about 1 million rows. Is there a faster way to do this in python/pandas ?

```
def add_rolling_vars(df, feats, amounts, group):
#creates rolling stats for a list of feats(columns) over a list of amounts[12,48](window sizes)
#grouped by a group like $gvkey or $sector
orig_feats = feats.copy()
new_feats= []
for amount in amounts:
    for name in feats:
        df[group+'_'+name+f'_{amount}_sma'] = df.groupby(group)[name].rolling(amount,1).mean().values
        df[group+'_'+name+f'_{amount}_std'] = df.groupby(group)[name].rolling(amount,1).std().values
        df[group+'_'+name+f'_{amount}_min'] = df.groupby(group)[name].rolling(amount,1).min().values
        df[group+'_'+name+f'_{amount}_max'] = df.groupby(group)[name].rolling(amount,1).max().values
        df[group+'_'+name+f'_{amount}_med'] = df.groupby(group)[name].rolling(amount,1).median().values
        df[group+'_'+name+f'_{amount}_25Q'] = df.groupby(group)[name].rolling(amount,1).quantile(.25).values
        df[group+'_'+name+f'_{amount}_75Q'] = df.groupby(group)[name].rolling(amount,1).quantile(.75).values
```

As an example, I also created this function that runs on the same dataset in about 1 min. Obviously, it's different because it doesn't have to iterate through windows of rows, but I still can pass a list of feats instead of name in feats and then add the whole transformed output to my dataframe using a list comprehension naming scheme:

```
def add_cat_stats(df,feats,group):
    #feats is a list of continuous feats to compute the monthly stats of       
    df[[group+'_'+name+'_avg' for name in feats]] = df.groupby([group,'Date'])[feats].transform('mean')
    df[[group+'_'+name+'_std' for name in feats]] = df.groupby([group,'Date'])[feats].transform('std')
    df[[group+'_'+name+'_min' for name in feats]] = df.groupby([group,'Date'])[feats].transform('min')
    df[[group+'_'+name+'_max' for name in feats]] = df.groupby([group,'Date'])[feats].transform('max')
    df[[group+'_'+name+'_med' for name in feats]] = df.groupby([group,'Date'])[feats].transform('median')
```

UPDATE

len(amounts) = 2

len(feats)= 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get @John Zwinck code to work but it did give me this idea to reformat the code which drops the time from 30min to 4min 45sec which is great! It'd be nice to get it down further but this is a workable solution:

```
def add_rolling_vars(df, feats, amounts, group):
    for amount in amounts:
        grouped = df.groupby(group)[feats].rolling(amount,1)
        prefix = ['_'.join([group, name, str(amount)]) for name in feats]
        df[[pre+'_sma' for pre in prefix]] = grouped.mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
        df[[pre+'_std' for pre in prefix]] = grouped.std().reset_index(0,drop=True)
        df[[pre+'_min' for pre in prefix]] = grouped.min().reset_index(0,drop=True)
        df[[pre+'_max' for pre in prefix]] = grouped.max().reset_index(0,drop=True)
        df[[pre+'_med' for pre in prefix]] = grouped.median().reset_index(0,drop=True)
        df[[pre+'_25Q' for pre in prefix]] = grouped.quantile(.25).reset_index(0,drop=True)
        df[[pre+'_75Q' for pre in prefix]] = grouped.quantile(.75).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```